# I'm working on a short where there are three actors, all wearing VANS shoes. Would you use a different pair of vans for each actor?

Tags: foley, recording, footsteps, group

The short is about a coach who's trying to teach his players how to play baseball. All of the players are wearing vans in the scenes and the surfaces range from the dirt on a baseball, concrete, and grass.

Would you guys use different pairs of vans for each actor even though they're the same on picture? I don't want the foot steps to walk over each other, no pun intended.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe record a quick test with three different Foley artists wearing the same shoes and see if the difference in the persons weight is enough?

Answer (score 2):

I'd tend to think more about the characters than what they are literally wearing. Is one dude goofy and heavy-footed? Is one more nimble? Does Jimmy only have one leg? etc

Answer (score 0):

I have many pairs of Vans shoes and quite honestly I can not audibly tell them apart. As James said, I would focus more on the characters than the shoes.